# C# Client port different from specified

Tags: c#, tcp, client

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient joao = new TcpClient("localhost", Convert.ToInt32(25565));
        MessageBox.Show(joao.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
        NetworkStream ns = joao.GetStream();
        byte[] outbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
        ns.Write(outbytes, 0, outbytes.Length);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Sent : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outbytes));
        ns.Close();
        joao.Close();
    }
```

So, this is the code i wrote for a c# client. The problem is that the output of the messageBox is "127.0.0.1:52296" and it keeps changing as i send more messages to the server. Shouldn't it be "127.0.0.1:25565" ? When i try to do it over internet it doesnt't work

Comment: `joao.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString()` should be like `joao.Client.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString()`

Comment: That doesn't exist i think :/ It doesn't contain a definition for "Port"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking out definition of the [TcpClient()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload you are using, you define the destination port as **25565**, means you connect to that remote port.

The [`Client`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object you are echoing is in reality is a [`Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has a property object called [`LocalEndPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Now that you could ask this [`EndPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object about its [`Port`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.port%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

**About why the given `EndPoint.Port` keeps changing:**

It's sort of about how the [TCP stack](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.4) works, if you don't reuse that socket it will keep changing, it's normal.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize TcpClient with address and port, you specify the host you want to connect to:
[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx)

So your destination host's port will always be 25565, but the port the client uses to reach the host can vary (chooses randomly an available port).